# How to show the \refstepcounter{figure} in list of figure

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, captions

This is my latex document. The figure is inside the table environment, the figure shows a caption but the list of figures doesn't show. please anyone can explain what else can I do to correct

```
\begin{center}
\centering 
  
  \begin{longtable}{ | m{3cm} | c | m{6cm} | }
   \caption{my.Lboro Analysis}
   \label{tbl:myLboro} \\
    \hline
    Type by shape & Figure & Attributes \\ 
    \hline
    \hline
   
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable{} -- Types} \\          
    \hline
     
      Type by shape & Figure & Attributes \\
      
     \hline
     \hline
     \endhead
     
     \hline
     \multicolumn{3}{c}{Table continuation in next page} \\      
     \hline
     \endfoot

    \hline 
    
    \endlastfoot
    
    
      Applicator brush
    
    &
     
    \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
    
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=30mm]{applicator}
     \refstepcounter{figure}
     \small
      Figure~\thefigure: Single spiral double stem brush. 
     % \caption{Single spiral double stem brush.}
      
    \end{minipage}
   
    
    & 
    %\begin{minipage}{5cm}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item They are use to apply substance on or to any object.
        \item Handles are made up of Nylon, Acetal, Aluminium, Brass or Stainless steel. 
        \item Fill material consist of Aluminium, Brass, Horse hair or titanium.
        \item They can be single end or double ended brushes.
        \item They are Autoclavable, Static Dissipative or Conductive.
      \end{itemize}
    %\end{minipage}
    \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
  
\end{center}
```

Comment: It will appear in the list of *tables*. By the way, `center` and `\centering` are not needed.

Comment: The table is appearing in the list of tables but there are some figures in the table which I want to show in the list of figures. After using the refstep counter the figures in table have the correct figure number and the caption is also shown but that figure number is not showing in the list of figures.

Answer (score 1):

After setting the figure caption, add the caption to the LoF via

```
\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\numberline{\thefigure}<caption>}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\listoffigures

\begin{longtable}{ c c c }
  \caption{Table caption} \\
  \hline
  First & Second & Third \\
  \begin{minipage}{.25\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \refstepcounter{figure}%
    Figure~\thefigure: Example image A
    \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\numberline{\thefigure}Example image A}
  \end{minipage} &
  \begin{minipage}{.25\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \refstepcounter{figure}%
    Figure~\thefigure: Example image B
    \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\numberline{\thefigure}Example image B}
  \end{minipage} &
  \begin{minipage}{.25\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \refstepcounter{figure}%
    Figure~\thefigure: Example image C
    \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\numberline{\thefigure}Example image C}
  \end{minipage} \\
  \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this helped me a lot and now it functions properly....

Comment: @PalanKashyapPK: If this answered your question, consider accepting it as such. See [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764)